# why dose my app in android shows wrong size of External memory?

Tags: android, android-external-storage

i want to get size of External memory in my app. my code doesn't work properly because i have 16 Gb External Memory size but my app shows me 5 GB :

```
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StatFs;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getTotalExternalMemorySize();

}
public boolean externalMemoryAvailable() {
    return android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
}
public void getTotalExternalMemorySize() {
    TextView textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ExternalSize);
    if (externalMemoryAvailable()) {
        File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
        long blockSize = stat.getBlockSizeLong();
        long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCountLong();
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(totalBlocks * blockSize/1073741824));
//1073741824 to convert to GB
    }else{
        textView.setText("There is no External memory");
    }
}
}
```

i don't know why, i will appreciate to show me what's wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question and explain, **in detail**, what "my code doesn't work properly" means.

Comment: i have 16Gb External size memory but my app shows me 5 GB i don't know why